# tomahawk panelNavigation2 does not triggered actionlistener after upgrading to JSF2

Tags: jsf, wildfly, tomahawk

I have migrated my web application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1. 
In my web.xml I have set the the following context-param to true in order to use bundle jars instead of using the provided wildfly jars.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have placed the following jars into the WEB-INF/libs folder:

```
tomahawk21-1.1.14, jsf-api-2.1.0.jar and jsf-impl-2.1.0.jar
```

I can start the application und log myself in. However once I click on a MenuItem built as follows:

```
<h:form id="nav" styleClass="nav">
    <t:panelNavigation2 id="panel-nav" expandAll="true">
        <t:navigationMenuItems value="#{hello.menuItems}" />
    </t:panelNavigation2>
</h:form>
```

nothing happens. I have programmatically set actionListener for the MenuItem. It did work fine when using JSF1.2.
Using remote debugging with eclipse clearly proves that the action listener method is not called.

Best regards
Edmond

Comment: Why such an ancient implementation? If you need JSF 2.1, pick the current latest JSF 2.1 implementation, not the first one. That's 2.1.29, not 2.1.0, which differs 3 full years of testing/enhancing/bugfixing. Do that first in order to exclude an already long fixed bug from being the cause.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time combining the jsf jars to see which combination is working with tomahawk and it seems as the only jsf2 working with tomahawk is exactly the combinatoin mentioned above. Using jsf-api-2.1.29.jar and jsf-impl-2.1.29.jar with either of the tomahawk.jar for jsf2 throws the following error: Unable to process annotations for url, vfs:/content/application.ear/lib/tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty